# How to view the console.log of an application whose terminal is closed

Tags: 14.04, command-line, putty

I am completely new to Linux and Ubuntu.

I have a Node Js application in which the console logs the data to the terminal. The application runs on a particular port.

I run the application by connecting to the server using Putty.

When I close Putty, the app runs in the background.

The next time I connect using putty, the logs are not displayed and the current port has to be closed and the app has to be restarted again.

Is there is any way I can see the console log when I run Putty anew?

Comment: You have tagged a LTS or ESM release (14.04 LTS is off-topic because it's EOL, all ESM releases are off-topic here as only supported by Canonical through Ubuntu Advantage).  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  (FYI: Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format, showing the release, ie. 14.04 was from 2015.April and its five years of free supported ended awhile back)

Comment: Tip: spent some time learning "screen".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible way might be to launch your application using screen

```bsh
screen -d -m yourexecutable
```

To reattach, you can

```bsh
screen -r yourexecutable
```

A great doc on how to use screen on a ssh session can be found here (https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/screen and https://ma.ttias.be/screen-a-must-for-ssh/ )

Answer (score 2):

You can print the output of the command in another file suppose you have run `npm start` command for starting your node server than change the command like this `npm start > log.txt`

Hope it will help you.